# Transliteration behavior (tr program in shell)

Tags: shell, glob, tr

I understand the basic behavior of tr but am confused when sets and sequences become involved. Some examples:

```
$ tr 'a' '[0]'
aaaaaa
[[[[[[
$ tr 'a-z' '[0-9]'
abcdef
[01234
$ tr 'a-z' '[*]'
abcde
[*]]]
$ tr 'a-z' '[\n]'
abcdef
[
]]]]
$ tr 'a-z' '[\n*]'
abcdef






$ tr 'a-z' '\n'
abcdef
```

It seems to me that in some cases (like with the `[\n*]`) it correctly interprets the set, but in other cases, it seems to stall at the closing bracket and continuously output that. I had thought that sets `[]` mean "any one of the enclosed characters", and that `*` would not be treated as a special char within the set. It seems like this holds true in some cases but not others. What is going on here?

Also, it seems to me that `tr 'a-z' '\n'` performs the same action as `tr 'a-z' '[\n*]`. Is there some nuance I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` only have special meaning if you are providing the set in the form `[CHAR*]`, `[CHAR*REPEAT]`, `[:POSIXCLASS:]`, or `[=CHAR=]`.

From your examples, only `tr 'a-z' '[\n*]'` is interpreted as set ("in SET2, copies CHAR until length of SET1"); all other examples are interpreted literally.

So `tr 'a-f' '[*]'` is identical to writing `tr 'abcdef' '[*]'` and will translate a→[, b→*, c→], d→], e→], f→].

`tr 'a-f' '[\n*]'` however is identcal to writing `tr 'abcdef' '\n\n\n\n\n\n'` and will replace every character with a newline. For a single character, this is already the default with `tr`, so you could have simply written `tr 'a-f' '\n'` as you have found out with your last example.

Comment: However, this is different for `grep`, is it not?

Comment: Example as such: `echo -e "foo\nfuo\nfaa" | grep f[ou]`

Comment: @user8393252 `grep` is a different program and generally uses regular expressions. Your question was about `tr` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1p.html)).

Comment: I’m used to `grep` as I learned regex in that context. What standard exactly are you describing?

Comment: so `tr` isn’t using regex?

Comment: I'm simply quoting from the `tr` [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1p.html). No, it isn't using regex. Have you read the manual?

Comment: Apparently not carefully enough. Thanks @knittl